# Google Colab can't get DNATokenizer

Tags: python, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, bioinformatics

I'm trying to run DNABERT in Google Colab. The problem I am having is that I can't import DNATokenizer.

https://github.com/jerryji1993/DNABERT

For example: Running:
`from transformers import BertModel, BertConfig, DNATokenizer`

results in the error:

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in <cell line: 1>()
> ----> 1 from transformers import BertModel, BertConfig, DNATokenizer
> ImportError: cannot import name 'DNATokenizer' from 'transformers' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/**init**.py)

I have tried:

```
!git clone https://github.com/jerryji1993/DNABERT
%cd DNABERT
!python3 -m pip install --editable .
%cd examples
!python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

However, I end up with:

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
```

I have also tried installing transformers==4.20.0 without luck.

Any advice would be great.

I'm using Google Colab and can't actually import DNATokenizer. I end up with the error